# Can you tell who own's an IP address? Like a whois lookup but for IPs

Tags: ip, whois

I'm renting a VPS from a company and I wanted to not be associated with this IP. Mostly for free speech reasons (life blog) to prevent doxxing.

Anyway I registered the domain privately, and I rented a separate VPS just for this site/others that need anonymity.

Again my purpose isn't to attack people, I want to speak my mind (cringe worthy thoughts, complaining about my life, poverty, etc) but not have it lead back to me so I lose my job. That sort of thing.

Comment: The IP is not yours, but from your provider. Do a `whois` query on it and you will see your provider data, not yours. However there is a myriad of other trails to you besides this. For example, if you did buy a domain name, what data did you use for registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell who owns an IP address by looking at BGP routing tables, but that shouldn’t be a concern for you, because the IP address is owned by the company you rent the VPS from, not by you. The trail should stop with them.

Comment: you can use... `whois ip.ad.re.ss` to get those informations. A few hosting providers allow to set the ip whois (at least for RIPE) but since that's not by default still no worry about it.

Comment: thanks @Mike. Yeah I am not renting the IP directly, just a VPS. Good to know, I wasn't sure if I had to set a reverse proxy or something. Thanks A.B I did check a whois ip and it returns the hosting provider's company name.

Comment: BGP is about routing, it says nothing about who owns an IP just how to get to it. RIRs have this data and it can be accessed through `whois` indeed. It will show LIRs allocations.